# Why does the UK CAA restart its page numbering with every new chapter of their CAP publications?

Tags: easa-regulations, easa, caa-uk-regulations, publications

Every CAA Publication (CAP) seems to restart its page numbering when starting a new chapter. Does anyone know why they have decided to do this?

For example, the [CAP413](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/modalapplication.aspx?catid=1&pagetype=65&appid=11&mode=detail&id=6973). Instead of a logical page number ordering throughout the document, you have to reference it as chapter 4, pg 4 or chapter 5, pg 2.

It makes it very difficult to reference information to others. It also makes navigating as a PDF challenging - many of the CAPs are solely in PDF format. (Often you can only view one page at a time, and it is so easy to get lost in a document which restarts its page ordering).

Is there a reason why the CAA has done this? What would be the formal or best way of referencing a CAP page?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's an artefact of a different era. Before computers were used to create documentation, updating large documents was difficult and expensive. People tried to reduce the workload by using chapter-page numbering. When you have to add pages to a book, chapter-page numbering allows you to replace one chapter instead of having to reprint the whole book.

Some organizations even supplied book updates as individual pages with a 'list of effective pages' so you could swap them out in your copy.

Nowadays there's no reason to keep doing this. Rebuilding a document (generate the TOC and crossreferences) is cheap, printing is cheap. You already noticed the big disadvantages of chapter-page numbering to the user.

Why they're still doing this? Inertia, probably.

How to reference them? Page 5-2 works, and if you want to be comprehensive, page 5-2 (PDF page 124).

(sorry, no references. Just lots of experience building large documents)

Comment: I think the UK government invented inertia.

Comment: Yep the CAA are perhaps the most backward government department technologically. I have it on fairly good authority that their very delayed "new computer system" is to replace an old system using Win95 terminals.

Comment: @GdD Unfortunately, Newton didn't take over the Royal Mint until a decade after inventing inertia.

Comment: There's still NT in places @Jamiec in the UK gov. I am not kidding. A few years ago in a a non-government client I found OS2! I thought it must have been a mis-detection, but no, it was in charge of a critical industrial control system!

Comment: @GdD: If you think that's amusing, you'll love this: In October, the United States Air Force [announced](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/24/us/nuclear-weapons-floppy-disks.html) that it had worked out how to launch a nuclear missile(!) without using 8-inch floppy disks.

Comment: If some chapters will change much more often than others, but the chapters that change infrequently will often be cited, chapter-page numbering offers advantages to users as well as publishers.  If I have a citation for page 5-137 of the 49th edition, and I have the 53rd edition, but chapter 5 hasn't changed, the relevant text would be found on page 5-11 of my edition even if chapter 4 had gained 19 pages.

Comment: @Kevin in their defence, if there’s one system I *really* don’t want to be screwed up after an “improvement”, the nuclear launch system is probably it. Relying on an old system has downsides, but the upside is: it’s worked for 50 years, and it’s likely to keep working for another 20...